# Extract multiple JsonPath values from returned Response using Rest Assured

Tags: json, rest-assured, jsonpath

I need to obtain two values from JSON response data returned from a Rest Assured modelled request:

```js
    public void getCustomerStatuses() {

        Response response =

        given().header("X-AC-User-ID","test-user").
                spec(customerApiSpec).
        when().
                get("/api/v6/status/" + ref + "/").
        then().
                assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response();

        custStatusId = response.path("$.cust[?(@.name=='STATUS_ID')].id");
        custRenewalId = response.path("$.cust[?(@.name=='RENEWAL_ID')].id");

        System.out.println(custStatusId);
        System.out.println(custRenewalId);

    }
```

This throws and `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '$.cust[?' @ line 1, column 36. $.cust[?(@.name=='STATUS_ID')].id`

What is the correct, best way of obtaining these?  I'm aware I can chain `extract().response().jsonPath();` off the request but not sure how I can obtain >1 value

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use [JsonPath](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/json-path/latest/io/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html)

```
    Response response =

    given().header("X-AC-User-ID","test-user").
            spec(customerApiSpec).
    when().
            get("/api/v6/status/" + ref + "/").
    then().
            assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response();

    JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();
```

If the received json body is this;

```
{
  "value1":{
    "id": 1,
    "abc": {
        "v1": "o1",
        "v2": "o2"
    }
  },
  "value2":{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "test2"
  }  
}
```

Then use the `get(String path)` method;

```
    String v1 = jsonPath.get("value1.abc.v1"); // o1
    String title = jsonPath.get("value2.title"); //  test2
```

Required import;

```
io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
```